# cUrl on instagram to lookup accounts by email

Tags: php, curl, instagram, libcurl, user-profile

Is it possible to search for an user (Not by their api https://api.instagram.com) but using php cUrl through the search box in their website at https://www.instagram.com/ (you have to login to see the search box at the top of the page)
I mean I know how to make a php script and make it log in and keep the session (learned from tutorials) but the problem is there are no `action=""` attribute in the form tag, nor there are any `name=""` attribute in their input tags.

- I want to know what they are using as their backend?
- I want to know how Instagram pass variables if their are no action and name attribute
- How can I post using cUrl without the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

The form input doesn't necessarily need a name attribute and also doesn't need to be in a form element with an action tag. Javascript could be used to get the input data and sent to the server using ajax or maybe change the address to search for what has been inputed.
Basically javascript could be used to get the data. In this case you won't be able to use cURL if you don't know the url that receives the input on the server.